# How can I change website content that is not accessible through wordpress dashboard?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How would you go about changing the text line 'Objective 1 000 000 $' at http://oratory360.com/

I have changed every single thing I can on the wordpress dashboard, and that line is NOT accessible through Pages, Options, Theme editor or anywhere else.

Comment: That content appears to be added into the site via a script.  If you look at where the donate button takes you, it's here: https://www.imakeanonlinedonation.org/fondationosj/

Since the donated values appear to be dynamic I'm guessing the "I Make An Online Donation" site has an API and some scripts that are basically hooked into the theme.
So I imagine to change that '1 000 000 $' you would need to get someone with the credentials to the account to go in there and adjust the objective/target of the fundraiser.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @TonyDjukic however https://www.imakeanonlinedonation.org/fondationosj/ is simply an external link, which I specified myself in the admin dashboard. When I edit the homepage http://oratory360.com/ I can see that it seems to be named post_9.php, but for the life of me I can't find a post_9.php anywhere insied wp. Is it perhaps only accessible in cPanel?

Comment: What's named `post_9.php`?  The home page is `page-id-71`.

Comment: My mistake. In the URL at Edit>Page I can see ?post=9&action=edit. I thought '9' was the post ID.

Comment: If that's what it says then it is... ...but, when you look at the source of the home page you see this: `<body class="home page-template page-template-template-home page-template-template-home-php page page-id-71">`  So it says it's page ID 71 based on the body tag.  When you edit, change the `?post=71&action=edit` and see what comes up.  The home page is using template-home.php, so also look into that file. (Do you have FTP access?)

Comment: changing the URL to post=71 shows me the same interface. I don't have FTP access at the moment, I have requested it.

Comment: It would be the same interface but is it the exact same content?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, exact same thing displayed on the screen, interface and content.

Comment: Well that's the page that's being used as the home page - so if the content isn't in there it's in `template-home.php`.  Not sure why you can't find it using the theme editor but you should be able to locate it via PHP.  Sorry this is so complex, some devs really make things confusing for no reason at all.

Comment: That's the thing, I've text searched every .php file I could find in the the Theme Editor for 'objective' — the dozen or so that would make sense to me, at least, such as functions.php, but I can only find references to obscure things that I can't find anywhere else, such as <main id=home> and ($section_1['content'])... I think I'm screwed unless I get access to FTP. I have a hunch what I'm looking for is in sidebar.php.